# Почему возникает ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, внутри класса есть задание конфига:

```
public $config = array(
    'api_key' => '8a29125664722e968987b085cf3a',
    'offer_id' => $offer_id,
    'user_id' => 3291,
);
```

Ругается на строчку с offer_id. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Наверняка переменная не определена.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov нет такая ошибка возникает если, ожидалось какой либо знак к примеру > этот. Если не определена переменная то ошибка уровня notice Undefined variable: offer_id

Comment: Покажите код выше, как минимум определение переменной `$offer_id` и модификаторы класса.

Answer (score 1):

Поля класса нельзя инициализировать неконстантными выражениями.
Вы можете передать нужное значение в метод класса или в конструктор.

```
class A {
  public $config = array(
    'api_key' => '8a29125664722e968987b085cf3a',
    'offer_id' => null,
    'user_id' => 3291,
  );
  public function __construct($offer_id) {
    $this->config['offer_id'] = $offer_id;
  }
}
```

Но много лучше:

```
class A {
  private $config;
  public function __construct($config) {
    $this->config = $config;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы решил эту задачу так

```
public function setConfigOffer($id){
  if($id) $this->config['offer_id']=$id;
  else return false;
}
```

а эту строчку бы вычеркнул - по моему взгляду она противоречит моим представлениям о создании классов

Comment: А я бы за такой код руки бы оторвал :D плюс ошибка не в этом

Comment: @Naumov подскажите пожалуйста пример - в каком случае в значении  свойстве класса указывается переменная, насколько я понимаю когда мы пишем класс - мы пишем чертеж, а уже после создания экземпляра класса можем присвоить свойству этого экземпляра значение переменной. В крайнем случае можно в классе указать ссылку на переменную - но это выглядит очень дико и не понятно какую цель преследует